# Gmail: Notify Delegate of New Email?

Tags: gmail

I set up a new Gmail account for a project and set my primary email as a delegate. Is there an easy way to get notified if I get new emails on my new account without checking in every 3 hours?

I'm not using Google Apps, just the "Grant access to your account" feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a desktop program such as [Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html).  This is available for Windows and Mac.  Of course you probably can't do this if you're already using it for your main account.

An alternative option is to set up forwarding from the delegated account to your main account (Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> "Add a forwarding address" button).  Set this to your main email, and all email to your project account will be forwarded to your main address.

Answer (score 1):

you could probably have the new account open on chrome, or FF with the [notification system addon](https://superuser.com/questions/268665/firefox-addon-to-imitate-google-chromes-built-in-notification-system/268668#268668), and use that to notify you. There's also the rather old [gmail notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html) application.